# UITableView giving different output for iPhone 4s and iPhone 5 (both have iOS 6)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, iphone-5

I have created iPhone app where I have UITableView where I am showing list of users.

I have code as

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // new is JSON data of list of users...
    news = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }
    // here in cell I have code to assign data...
    return cell;
}
```

### Now when I add/ delete some users

In **iPhone 4s or below** it gives me updated list.

However in **iPhone 5**, it gives me previous list data (same data as before). Neither deleted data is removed from list NOR newly added users are shown in list.

**Note:**

When I run this app in Simulator using iPhone 5 simulator, it works properly.

I have proper delegeate and everything as its working perfectly with iPhone 4s and below. Just problem is with iPhone 5.

Any idea why such weird behavior is there with iPhone 5?

---

### Edit 1

The most shocking thing I see in this app is when I run app on iPhone 5 and see NSLog while adding data in UITableView, I see same NSLog as before... e.x. even if Id 5 data is not there, still I see id 5.

Any idea why this is happening? **This is really making me crazy...**

---

### Edit 2

Now again the shocking news is When I tried on my friend iPhone 5, it works great. ***But not on client iPhone 5 and now on iPhone 4 too**.

Any idea why this weird is happening?

Comment: Need more debug information. Log the contents of `news` on both platforms.

Comment: @Robert : When I check NSLog, I see same id's shown as before... even those are not present in database...